# Add caption/label to easylist

Tags: floats, pdftex, pdf, easylist

I want to add a caption (or a label) to a list. I figured out that I can do it with figures, but it's really messy

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]

    \vspace{-2em} %label format leaves empty space above the caption when empty

    \hspace\caption{\textbf{This is the caption...}}
    \begin{easylist}
        & first item
        & second item
        & ...
    \end{easylist}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I used `\paragraph{...}` and `\subparagraph{...}` before but the formatting in the compiled pdf isn't as nice

Answer (score 1):

So I just found out that you can do:

```
\begin{easylist}
    \noindent\textbf{Some caption}
    & First item
    & Second item
    & ...
\end{easylist}
```

Which works flawlessly ... but I didn't see it mentioned anywhere